# Newly created preact Component retains UI state of old component (different from react)

Tags: reactjs, preact

I have a simple Preact component which contains a checkbox:

```
class Cb extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<div>Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" /></div>);
  }
}
```

In a parent `Component`, this `Cb` is conditionally added like this:

```
{ this.state.show ? <Cb /> : <div>Nothing</div> }
```

Now for the strange part: If you follow these steps:

1. Check the checkbox
2. Toggle `state.show` in the parent `Component`, removing the `Cb`
3. Toggle `state.show` in the parent `Component` again, creating a new `Cb`

Then the newly created checkbox is still checked!
How is this possible? The checkbox is truely removed and a completely new `Cb` instance is created (I checked using log messages in the constructor). Where is this state stored?

Additional weirdness: *The behavior is different in React* (there, the newly created checkbox is not checked).

Here are two Codepens with the same code in [Preact](https://codepen.io/gei0r/pen/bQwELP?editors=1111) and [React](https://codepen.io/gei0r/pen/gQwPeq?editors=1111), where you can compare the behaviors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with how Preact recycles components. There is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/developit/preact/issues/461) along the same lines as what your question is. Now to fix the problem you will have to reset the checked value in `componentWillUnmount`

```
  componentWillUnmount () {
    this.cb.checked = false;
  }
```

Where `this.cb` is a ref to the checkbox.
Working [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RqEvgz?editors=1111) with the modification.
I made the checkbox a ref because there is another issue with componentWillUnMount and using querySelector (and its also shorter to type)

Edit: As commented this is only valid for preact 8.x. preact X removes component recycling.

Comment: FYI: We removed the recycler completely for Preact X. An alpha is scheduled to be released on March 4th 2019. _Disclaimer: I work on Preact_